How to integrate a `FewShotPromptTemplate` directly `create_pandas_dataframe_agent` from langchain
I'm developing an AI assistant designed for non-data science users to query a dataset. My current approach involves using a FewShotPromptTemplate to translate user queries into data science tasks, followed by a create_pandas_dataframe_agent to extract the required information from the dataset.
However, I'm encountering issues with the create_pandas_dataframe_agent as it does not consistently return the same answer for identical queries and sometimes fails to execute the queries correctly.
I would like to integrate the `FewShotPromptTemplate directly within the agent to improve performance and reliability. How can I achieve this?
I've experimented with the prefix langchain_experimental.agents.agent_toolkits.pandas.prompt import PREFIX, but the results have been suboptimal. Any suggestions or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
